# Edit and create with ng2-smart-table

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, smart-table

I am trying to use `<ng2-smart-table>`. The issue is that I don't know how to bind the plus button (`addButtonContent`) with some create function data. Now this just opens for me anther row to insert the data. Also how can I do it for the edit button.
My code is:

```
settings = {
   add: {
      addButtonContent: '<i class="ion-ios-plus-outline"></i>', //how to call some function to this one
      createButtonContent: '<i class="ion-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="ion-close"></i>',
   },
   edit: {
      editButtonContent: '<i class="ion-edit"></i>',
      saveButtonContent: '<i class="ion-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="ion-close"></i>',
   },
   delete: {
      deleteButtonContent: '<i class="ion-trash-a"></i>',
      confirmDelete: true
   },
```

and my template is:

```html
<ba-card title="Basic Example" baCardClass="with-scroll">
   <div class="form-group">
      <input  #search type="search" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Search..."  (keyup)="onSearch(search.value)">
   </div>
   <ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="source" (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)"></ng2-smart-table>
</ba-card>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

in your template add this

```
     <ng2-smart-table class='form-control' [settings]="settings" [source]="source"  (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)" (editConfirm)="onSaveConfirm($event)"
 (createConfirm)="onCreateConfirm($event)"  ></ng2-smart-table>
```

and then in your component call the new actions

```
onCreateConfirm(event):void { 
} 

onSaveConfirm(event):void {
}

onDeleteConfirm(event): void {
}
```

Comment: **Check @alvarosmh answer below as well to get the complete solution !**

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to comment on Yousef Al Kahky's answer but im new so i have to answer again:

You also have to add `confirmCreate: true`, otherwise the method won't be invoked.

```
add: {
  addButtonContent: '<i class="nb-plus"></i>',
  createButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
  cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
  confirmCreate: true,
},
```